# Verify that $F_i^M=(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)F_i^R=(I+(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1})F_i^R$

Tags: matrices, vectors

> Let $L$ and $\Psi$ be $p\times p$ matrices where
>   $\Psi=diag(\psi_1,\dots,\psi_p)$. If
>   $$F_i^M=(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}(X_i-\mu)$$
>
> $$F_i^R=L^T(LL^T+\Psi^{-1})(X_i-\mu)$$ where $X_i$ and $\mu$ are
>   $p\times 1$ vectors. Verify that
>   $$F_i^M=(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)F_i^R=(I+(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1})F_i^R$$

The first equality was easy to see because I just used a result that says
$$L^T(LL^T+\Psi)^{-1}=(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}$$
Then
$$(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)F_i^R=(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}(X_i-\mu)$$
$$=(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}(X_i-\mu)=F_i^M$$

I don't know how to check the last equality, I tried to use that
$$(I+(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1})=I^{-1}(I+(L^T\Psi^{-1}L))(L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}$$
and substitute $F_i^R$ but didn't worked.